# apply function for list of arrays

Tags: r

This is a newbie question, but I am having some problems in understanding the apply functions for datasets that are a list of arrays.

This is a example of the data I have and what I am trying to do:

```
> dataset1=array(data1,dim=c(2,10,5))
> dataset2=array(data2,dim=c(2,10,5))
> dataset3=array(data2,dim=c(2,10,5))
> datasets=list(data1=dataset1,data2=dataset2,data3=dataset3)
> str(datasets)
List of 3
 $ data1: num [1:2, 1:10, 1:5] 0.101 1.192 0.154 0.911 1.889 ...
 $ data2: num [1:2, 1:10, 1:5] 2.84 1.63 1.78 1.24 1.09 ...
 $ data3: num [1:2, 1:10, 1:5] 2.84 1.63 1.78 1.24 1.09 ...
```

I want to replace all values bellow 1.5 by 0

```
for (d in 1:3){
  for (n in 1:2){
    for (i in 1:10){
      datasets[[d]][n,i,][datasets[[d]][n,i,]<=1.5]=0
    }
  }
}
```

I wonder if I can I use one of the apply functions? Or for this type of dataset (list of arrays) or should I keep the loop method and forget about other options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With reproducible data:

```
dataset1 = array(rnorm(100),dim = c(2,10,5))
dataset2 = array(rnorm(100),dim = c(2,10,5))
dataset3 = array(rnorm(100),dim = c(2,10,5))
datasets = list(data1 = dataset1, data2 = dataset2, data3 = dataset3)
```

Now write an anonymous function to do the general replacement, and lapply with that across the list:

```
datasets.updated <- lapply(datasets, function(x) {x[x < 1.5] <- 0; x})
```

A rather tidier approach for the anonymous function, provided by dickoa:

```
datasets.updated <- lapply(datasets, function(x) ifelse(x < 1.5, 0, x))
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of ";" using R, but it works. So i'll just add this solution using "ifelse"  : lapply(datasets, function(x) ifelse(x < 1.5, 0, x)).

Comment: why don't you like to use ";". is it for a specific resaon?

Comment: here it's just syntax, with a semi-colon I can push it all on one line, it's just lazy - far better to put anonymous functions in a better layout, but that somehow means they should not be anonymous (to me). ifelse is a nice tidy up.

Comment: Note that mdsumner's original anonymous function is much faster with large datasets (I used `dataset1 = array(rnorm(100000000),dim = c(200,1000,500))`, etc, and the result was about 6.8 times faster than using `ifelse`).